# Using Html.RenderPartial() in ascx files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial

I'm trying to use Html.RenderPartial in acsx file
and I'm getting an error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   has no applicable method named 'RenderPartial' but appears to have an
>   extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically
>   dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the
>   extension method without the extension method syntax

```
<a href="/projects/<%=project.Id %>">
  <% Html.Label("fdf"); %>
  <% Html.RenderPartial("ProjectName", Model.Id); %></a></li>
 <%} %>
```

However I've import neccessary namespaces, so it won't be error at

```
<% Html.Label("fdf"); %>
```

Are there any methods to use Html.RenderPartial in ascx file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The compiler cannot choose the correct method because your Model is `dynamic`. Change the call to:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ProjectName", (int)(Model.Id)); %>
```

Or any other datatype Id is.

Comment: @Rob, if you ever switch to Razor, consider using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047543/render-partial-view-with-dynamic-model-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp-net-mvc-3/5357049#5357049

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone else made the same mistake I did:

```
@Model MyViewModel
```

This will treat your model as dynamic

```
@model MyViewModel
```

This is a correctly strongly typed view.  Note the lack of capitalisation!

Note, that this is Razor, unlike the original question.

Comment: Truly a bit of genius. It really helped save me time.

Answer (score 2):

The only way i found to pass eg. an IEnumerable was to create a local variable and pass in this one.
For Example
`@{
 IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Friend> friends = Model.Friends;
 Html.RenderPartial("_FriendsList", friends);
}`

`Html.RenderPartial("_FriendsList", (IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Friends>)(Model.Friends));` did not work!