# How to use dynamic model to partial view in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In one time I need to return IndexParty model. Next I need to return IndexPerson model to a view.

```
 public Tuple<IndexParty> GetTuple(){
     var tuple = new Tuple<IndexParty>(model);
     return tuple;
 }
```

My .cshtml class is here

```
@model Mymodel

<div class="hide partial-view" id="partyrelationship">
    @Html.Partial("../Party/Index", Mymodel)
</div>
```

Then I want to load as partial view.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a PartyController.cs (inheriting from  Controller) with an Index action that returns this model.

PartyController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return PartialView(GetTuple());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@model dynamic

<div class="hide partial-view" id="partyrelationship">
    @Html.Partial("../Party/Index", Model)
</div>
```

I would also move your partial to it's own controller action rather than using the index action.

Comment: When I try this it gave this error message 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Partial'

Comment: I would take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047543/render-partial-view-with-dynamic-model-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp-net-mvc-3